# Pandas eval returns error on date arithmetic using Timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, eval

When I try to use basic date arithmetic in Pandas' `eval()`, it gives the following error:

`Cannot convert input [1 days 00:00:00] of type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> to Timestamp`

The same expression run against the data frame works fine, though. Is this a feature of `eval()` or am I missing something?

A minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "date": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", periods=10, freq='D')
})

# works fine
df.date + pd.Timedelta('1D')

# errors out
df.eval("date + @pd.Timedelta('1D')")
```

Incidentally, the expression complains about undefined "pd", even if it's included in the `local_dict` parameter to `eval()`. The only way I found to get around it is with the `@` prefix. For what it's worth, I'm using the latest version of `pandas==1.5.2`.

Comment: What's the purpose of using `df.eval` and what's your _expected output_ ?

Comment: The expected output would be the same as running the expression normally. The purpose of using `eval()` in this context is to allow user to run simple arbitrary calculations on the dataframe by supplying a string expression that is passed to `eval()`. Could be `num_col + 1` or `date_col + pd.Timedelta('1D')`. Except, of course, that date arithmetic doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem like you're missing something. As a workaround, why not use Python standard library **eval** instead: `eval("df.date + pd.Timedelta('1D')")`?

Comment: There was an answer (now deleted) suggesting eval, but it's a lot more permissive than pandas' eval so I'd like to avoid it for security reasons.